# Cannot remove breakpoints in Firefox debugger

Tags: firefox, debug, firefox-developer-tools

I added some breakpoints in Firefox debugger and when I removed them, they just disappear in the Breakpoints list.Then, when I load the page, it still pauses at the breakpoints.

If I close the Developer Tools window and open it again, the breakpoints I removed will come back again. In that case, I cannot debug this page for its annoying pauses.

This issue occurred when Firebug still existed years ago. Is there any way to clean the breakpoints or reset the debugger?

Comment: Which version of Firefox?

Comment: Hello @spikey_richie it is 68.0.2 (64-bit) on Windows 10 1903

Comment: Is this still a problem with the latest version of Firefox (i.e. 72.0.1)? Then you should first try the latest Nightly version from https://nightly.mozilla.org and if it also occurs there, file a bug via https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi (in product 'DevTools' and component 'Debugger').

Comment: I'm still seeing this in Firefox 83. The closest bug I can see is https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1608816

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem.
I typically had a breakpoint on a line like this:

```
z.appendChild(document.createTextNode(......
```

Two breakpoint-marks were available, one on ***z*** and the other on ***appendChild***.
Finally I activated both, subsequently it paused.
Then I disabled both, one by one, and no unwanted pause anymore.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).